# How do I calculate the time difference between two datetimes in excel and then get the average time?

Tags: excel, datetime, average, difference

I have a dataset that I download from an application (no movement in changing the format of data)

```
**Created Date       | Reviewed Date**
2023-10-25T09:55:47  | 2023-10-28T10:23:56
2023-10-25T09:55:47  | 2023-10-28T10:23:56
2023-10-25T09:55:47  | *null*
2023-09-25T09:55:47  | 2023-09-28T10:23:56
2023-10-25T09:55:47  | 2023-10-28T10:23:56
2023-10-25T09:55:47  | 2023-10-27T10:23:56
2023-09-25T09:55:47  | 2023-10-28T10:23:56
2023-09-25T09:55:47  | 2023-10-28T10:23:56
```

I want to work out the average review time. This needs to be in excel.

My workings so far:

1. Convert the datetime format using
   `=DATEVALUE(MID(H2,1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(H2,12,8))`
   which gives me:

```
**Created Date    | Reviewed Date**
25/10/2023 09:55  | 28/10/2023 10:23
25/10/2023 09:55  | 28/10/2023 10:23
25/10/2023 09:55  | *null*
25/09/2023 09:55  | 28/09/2023 10:23
25/10/2023 09:55  | 28/10/2023 10:23
25/10/2023 09:55  | 27/10/2023 10:23
25/09/2023 09:55  | 28/10/2023 10:23
25/09/2023 09:55  | 28/10/2023 10:23
```

2. Get the datetime different between the two using
   `=TEXT(N4-M4,"dd")&" Days " & TEXT(N4-M4,"hh:mm")&" Minutes "` to get

```
03 Days 00:28 Minutes 
03 Days 00:28 Minutes 
#Value!
03 Days 00:28 Minutes
03 Days 00:28 Minutes
02 Days 00:28 Minutes
02 Days 00:28 Minutes
33 Days 00:28 Minutes
33 Days 00:28 Minutes
```

3. Get average time from all the values

Here is where I can't move any further. I have tried =AVERAGE(daterange).

**Expected output:**

Average time to review: 18 Days 00:28 Minutes

Comment: What output do you expect where `Created Date` is later than `Reviewed Date`? You got some instances like `25/10/2023 09:55  | 28/09/2023 10:23`. And what output do you expect if any date is null? How do null values should affect your average?

Comment: Ah sorry must have been a copy + paste error. The review date will always be after created date. Ill edit the example. Nulls should be ignored.

Comment: @james you could try this formula if you are using `MS365` --> `=AVERAGE(TOCOL(MAP(A2:A9,B2:B9,LAMBDA(x,y,SUM(TEXTSPLIT(y,"T")-TEXTSPLIT(x,"T")))),3))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya this definitely gives me what I'm looking for. I guess just need to work on the average. In the dataset, the review time is either 03 Days 00:28 Minutes or 03 Days 22:39 Minutes, so Im looking for something like average time is 03 Days 08:10 for reviews.

Comment: As @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Sir has mentioned you have not yet shown the expected output, please edit the post to show us what you have tried with the expect output as well!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Ive added expected output

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - I can confirm that you are a steely-eyed Excel man.